# ListView add columns programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a voting app, which has unknown amount of voters. I would like to add columns to ListView when I know the amount of voters. Here is an example image:
[image]

Is there a way to add columns to ListView dynamically? I have googled this for the past 2 hours and can't seem to find any good solution to this.

I already have vertical and horizontal scrolling working and I am able to add voter names on top, but I can't add vote points dynamically, since they are inside the ListView.

Here's what I have tried:

1. Inflate layout for ListView to add items (for some reason if I added for example "0", it added "0000" to the first row and "00" to the rest of the rows)
2. Use RecyclerView (it worked better than ListView, it added the "0" correctly, but for some reason the width was not what it was supposed to be

Comment: Use GridLayout as Item of listview

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to create this, so I though that I would share it in here. I used RecyclerView for doing it, but if anyone knows how to do this with ListView I will happily use that instead. It is probably possible to do this same thing by using view holders in ListView? I'll post my results if it works.

```
// Adapter for creating the RecyclerView
public class ResultsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<ListItem> itemsList;
    private ArrayList<Profile> profiles;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public View view;
        public TextView name, extra, votes;
        public TextView[] votePoints;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.resultsName);
            extra = view.findViewById(R.id.resultsBonus);
            votes = view.findViewById(R.id.resultsVotePoints);
            votePoints = new TextView[profiles.size()];
        }
    }


    public ResultsAdapter(Context context, List<ListItem> itemsList, ArrayList<Profile> profiles) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.profiles = profiles;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.result_show_votes_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ListItem item = itemsList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.extra.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTotal()));
        holder.votes.setText(String.valueOf(item.getVotePoints()));

        // Add vote points to layout
        LinearLayout layout = holder.view.findViewById(R.id.resultItemLayout);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        for (int i = 0; i < profiles.size(); i++) {
            ListItem voteItem = itemsList.get(position);
            Profile profile = profiles.get(i);
            int voteAmount = profile.votePointsOfItem(voteItem);

            // Use "layout" and "false" as parameters to get the width and height from result_voter_points
            TextView vote = (TextView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.result_voter_points, layout, false);
            vote.setText(voteAmount == 0 ? "" : String.valueOf(voteAmount));
            layout.addView(vote);

            holder.votePoints[i] = vote;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemsList.size();
    }
}
```

```
// Add profile names to topics
LinearLayout topicLayout = findViewById(R.id.topicLayout);
for (Profile p : selectedProfiles) {
    TextView name = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.result_voter_name, topicLayout, false);
    name.setText(p.getName());
    topicLayout.addView(name);
}

RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

ResultsAdapter adapter = new ResultsAdapter(this, selectedList.getItems(), selectedProfiles);
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this with the ListView, here is the solution:

```
// Add profile names to topics
LinearLayout topicLayout = findViewById(R.id.topicLayout);
for (Profile p : selectedProfiles) {
    TextView name = (TextView) 
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.result_voter_name,topicLayout, false);
    name.setText(p.getName());
    topicLayout.addView(name);
}

final ListView list = findViewById(R.id.resultItems);
ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, selectedList.getItems(),
                    selectedProfiles);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

```
// List View adapter
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ListItem> listData;
    private ArrayList<Profile> profiles;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public ListAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<ListItem> listData, ArrayList<Profile> profiles) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.profiles = profiles;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.result_show_votes_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ListItem item = listData.get(position);

        holder.name.setText(item.getName());
        holder.extra.setText(String.valueOf(item.getTotal()));

        // Loop through voters and update their given points
        for (int i = 0; i < profiles.size(); i++) {
            Profile profile = profiles.get(i);                  // Get profile
            TextView vote = holder.votePoints[i];               // Get textview for vote point
            int voteAmount = profile.votePointsOfItem(item);    // Get vote points amount for item
            vote.setText(voteAmount == 0 ? "" : String.valueOf(voteAmount));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    /**
     * Class for holding view data.
     */
    class ViewHolder {
        View view;
        TextView name, extra;
        public TextView[] votePoints;

        /**
         * Holds all the necessary data for the view.
         * @param view convertview
         */
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            this.view = view;
            name = view.findViewById(R.id.resultsName);
            extra = view.findViewById(R.id.resultsBonus);
            votePoints = new TextView[profiles.size()];

            // Add vote points to layout
            LinearLayout layout = view.findViewById(R.id.resultItemLayout);
            for (int i = 0; i < profiles.size(); i++) {
                // Use "layout" and "false" as parameters to get the width and height from result_voter_points
                TextView vote = (TextView) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.result_voter_points, layout, false);
                layout.addView(vote);
                votePoints[i] = vote;
            }
        }
    }
}
```